# Horizontal scroll using nowrap and inline-block

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I'm developing a horizontal scrolling gallery using `white-space: nowrap` and  `display: inline-block`. A gallery is composed of a series of image panes and a text pane at the end inside a container. You can look at an example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/zcf0va58/3/

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.post-image {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.post-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-text">
    <div>
      some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the text pane has a max-width, not a fixed width. This causes the container to shrink a bit. If a specify a fixed width in the text pane the container wraps around the child panes correctly:

https://jsfiddle.net/zcf0va58/4/

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.post-image {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.post-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="http://uc48.net/europeana/images/fpo_square.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="post-text">
    <div>
      some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this the expected behaviour? Is there a way to get the container to wrap around the child panes correctly without having to specify a fixed width in the text pane?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is due to the `white-space` and `max-width` values that being used together. You can try using flexbox instead, since it doesn't need to use `white-space: nowrap;` for such layout.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7p0h5ga/)**

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.post-image {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.post-text {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/100/ccc">
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/100/999">
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/100/ccc">
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/100/999">
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/100/ccc">
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/100/999">
  </div>
  <div class="post-text">
    <div>
      some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also try the CSS table layout if it needs to run on legacy browsers.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6u2fgf1o/)**

```css
.container {
  display: inline-table;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.post-image, .post-text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.post-text {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/100/ccc">
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/100/999">
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/100/ccc">
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/100/999">
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/100/ccc">
  </div>
  <div class="post-image">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/100/999">
  </div>
  <div class="post-text">
    <div>
      some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the code to run in older browsers, so using flexbox right now is not an option. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: OK, I updated above added css table approach, let me know if that works.